# the definition of irrational numbers and the proof of Cauchy's theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

[At page 281 of The History of the Calculus and its Conceptual Development](https://archive.org/stream/TheHistoryOfTheCalculusAndItsConceptualDevelopment/Boyer-TheHistoryOfTheCalculusAndItsConceptualDevelopment#page/n293/mode/1up)
[image]
Why the necessity of the condition here doesn't require a previous definition of the system
of real numbers, especially the definition of irrational numbers, but the proof of the
sufficiency of the condition does ?

Comment: Good question +1. This is one of the reasons real numbers are needed. It is important that we understand the need for real numbers and as well as how the real numbers satisfy this need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the concepts of limit for functions and sequences can be defined over the system of rational numbers also. If you see the definitions of these concepts they are only based on density property of the numbers in question. Both systems of rationals and reals have density property, both have order relations and both are fields. There is no difference between them apart from the completeness property.

It is completeness of real numbers which ensures that many interesting limits exist. Thus based on definitions we can prove that every sequence (in any system either rational or real) which has limit (in the same system) also satisfies the Cauchy's criterion. But to prove the converse (which is related to existence of limits) we must use completeness of real numbers. In the system of rational numbers we do have Cauchy sequences which have no limit.

To convince yourself, you should prove that the sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ defined by $$x_{1}=1,x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_{n}+\frac{2}{x_{n}}\right)$$ is a sequence of rational numbers which satisfies Cauchy's criterion, but there is no rational number to which this sequence converges. It is this inadequacy of rationals (which BTW is very technical in nature compared to the other inadequacy which Dedekind observed) which led Cantor to develop the theory of real numbers as Cauchy sequences of rationals.

---

Now that we have sound theories of real numbers at our disposal no one really bothers to ponder over the need for real/irrational numbers in mathematics. But throughout history mathematicians felt that there was something deeply lacking in the rational numbers which could not be supplied by algebra (that is by adding algebraic numbers to the field of rationals). Most mathematicians took the shortcut and assumed the existence of real numbers with the desired property to fix what was lacking in the rationals. All this was based on intuition and only in nineteenth century came rigorous theories of real numbers which put them on a sound foundation.

And it seems that history repeats itself. Modern analysis textbooks and curriculum again takes real numbers for granted (the axiomatic approach to real numbers) and the students are almost never aware of the need / importance of real numbers. And those theories of real numbers are thought of as just some set theoretic stuff on par with Peano's axioms.

Comment: Thank you! You did give another clear and deep explanation, helped me very much again ! I am nearly holding the same opinion with you! Within rational number system, there are sequences of rational numbers with rational limits which are Cauchy, but a sequence of rational numbers which is Cauchy might have limit out of the rational number system , so that caused the need for a  number system with completeness property.

Comment: As for the need for real/irrational numbers, I think by questioning "Why all rational numbers along with all the irrational numbers could form a continuous domain(the number continuum)" would interest learners to explore so that lead to the Dedekind Cut.

Comment: @iMath: Dedekind was working with the axiom that we can map real numbers with points on a straight line as a bijection. Dedekind realized the the fundamental aspect of the straight line called continuity and expressed the essence of continuity of line as follows : *If we break a horizontal line into two parts via cutting at a point then one of the parts contains the point which was used to cut the line and it also contains all the points to the left of it. The other part of the broken line will contain rest of the points.*

Comment: @iMath: Dedekind then proved that if we assume that rationals can be mapped bijectively with points of a line then the above continuity property of the line can not hold. And thus he understood that rationals cannot give a complete picture of the line and hence there is a need to find numbers which can map the points of line and have a property corresponding to the property of continuity of a line. Using these ideas Dedekind defined what is called a 'section'  or a 'cut'.

Comment: @iMath: you must read Dedekind's original paper "Continuity and irrational numbers" (it's available online) to get a deeper understanding of the real numbers. It is written in a much better style than most analysis textbooks.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to understand the number continuum nearly a year ago thus found Dedekind's pamphlet that you mentioned https://www.gutenberg.org/files/21016/21016-pdf.pdf I've read it till chapter V of first part, is it necessary to read through the full book? BTW, I would discuss Russell's definition of irrational numbers and his criticism to Dedekind for using the axiom with you later([learn more here](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=gMdyCwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA187&dq=russell%20dedekind%20segment%20of%20rational&hl=zh-CN&pg=PA187#v=onepage&q=russell%20dedekind%20segment%20of%20rational&f=true))

Comment: @iMath: reading that pamphlet upto chapter 5 is sufficient. Btw the link regarding Russell did not open in my browser because it says "thus page is not available for preview". But no worry I will search it on my own.

Answer (score 2):

Consider any metric space $(X,d)$. Let $\epsilon >0. $If $(x_n)\subset X$ converges to $x\in X$ then $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n>N, d(x_n,x)<\frac{\epsilon}{2}.$ Now let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ be such that $m,n>N$. Invoking triangle inequality you prove that $d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon$, whence $(x_n)$ is Cauchy.

This result holds true for any metric space. However the convergence of a Cauchy sequence to a point in the given metric space depends on the space. In fact metric spaces in which all Cauchy sequences are convergent are called complete metric spaces. Now the space $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete. But $\mathbb{R}$ is complete. Note that $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}\bigcup(\mathbb{R-Q})$ where $\mathbb{R-Q}$ is the set of irrationals defined accordingly. I think this is what the author meant.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy to show that if $x_n \to x$ then $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence directly.

To show that if $(x_n)_n$ is Cauchy, then $x_n \to x$ for some $x$ is a bit harder. If the $x_n$'s were rational and we were seeking a rational $x$, then this would be impossible. It follows that we need to work with irrational numbers as well.

Comment: "It is very easy to show that if $x_n \to x$ then $(x_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence directly. "How can you ensure $x$ in this statement is not an irrational number?

Comment: You don't care about this : you can do it in any metric space, I think that's what is meant there. Whereas the sufficiency condition only holds in special metric spaces